# nokogiri 1.9.1 install failed on MacOS Catalina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am getting an error and bundle install fails:
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.9.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.9.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

I have tried many commands from stack overflow but no luck yet.
After reading some posts about the issue I added the following environment variables but the `bundle install` still fails.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libxslt/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libxslt/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libxslt/include"
```

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -v "1.9.1" -- --use-system-libraries
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/wiii/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in libxslt/xslt.h... no
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... no
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -llibxslt... no
-----
libxslt is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/wiii/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-exslt-dir
    --without-exslt-dir
    --with-exslt-include
    --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
    --with-exslt-lib
    --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libexslt-config
    --without-libexslt-config
    --with-xsltlib
    --without-xsltlib
    --with-libxsltlib
    --without-libxsltlib

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Debugging info are attached below:

```
$ which ruby
/Users/wiii/.rbenv/shims/ruby
$ which bundle
/Users/wiii/.rbenv/shims/bundle
$ which gem
/Users/wiii/.rbenv/shims/gem
```

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin19.0]
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.17.3
$ gem --version
2.2.2
```

Homebrew

```
% brew list
ansible     kind        libxslt     openssl@1.0 ruby-build
autoconf    kubectx     libyaml     openssl@1.1 sqlite
gdbm        kubernetes-cli  mpdecimal   pkg-config  tcl-tk
go      libgcrypt   mysql@5.7   protobuf    tomcat@8
htop        libgpg-error    ncurses     python@3.9  xz
icu4c       libiconv    node        rbenv
k9s     libxml2     openjdk     readline
intellij-idea
```

Could anyone share some thoughts on what might be causing the issues here?

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri is an open source software library to parse HTML and XML in Ruby. It depends on libxml2 and libxslt to provide its functionality. without it Rails is non-functional.

it seems as if your macOS is missing some essential libraries required for nokogiri to run on your computer.

you can go ahead and first uninstall nokogiri and any other interfering library that you might have installed during your endeavor to solve this issue

run `brew uninstall nokogiri`

upon uninstalling, you can run `brew install libxml2 libxslt` to install the most essential libraries using brew

after that, run `gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby -- --use-system-libraries` to successfully install nokogiri